# ERROR: * Oculus SDK not found or older than 1.0

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

i wanna up load my android app's apk on Oculus appLap, then this issue happened, i did research and they suggested me to add OpenXR mobile SDK to my project, but i didnt get the detail documentation to add it, pls help me.

The sdk i dowloaded from Oculus is the folder, no clue how to add it to my Android project app.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Your Q lacks in several aspects and that should give you a hint how to improve it. Best take it offline for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem!!
First you have to download Oculus SDK from unity assets store
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-82022
then implement it in your unity project.
Second export unity project, you will get 3 following .aar files.

```
1.InteractionSdk.aar 
2.OVRPlugin.aar 
3.SDKTelemetry.aar
implementation(name: 'InteractionSdk', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'OVRPlugin', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'SDKTelemetry', ext:'aar')
```

Done~

Comment: thank for answering me, btw i got another issue that I built my android app on meta quest 2 and nothing show up but a black screen, no error log. Do u have any idea for this usse?